# Mapping user input from one DOM element to the renderer element using Three.js and TrackballControls.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to create a small container where the user will be able to move the mouse/drag his finger in order to control the renderer DOM element, in another container. The problem is that TrackballControls.js, a controller script included with THREE.js, maps the controls to event.clientX and event.clientY, so when I drag with in the small container I created, I don't see the desired effect. I was wondering what a proper way to map the input from a small area and effect the renderer element as if the user had the entire rendering area to give input?

The reason I need to do this is because I am integrating a CSS3D view into a normal, 2D page, and the mobile experience is awful if I do not disable to touch controls on TrackballControls.js- the user will be scrolling down the page as normal, and when he hits the 3D div, the 3D controls take over and the user can no longer scroll out of that area back to the rest of the page content. So I need a little small area where the user can spin, zoom, and pan my 3D visualization but then be able to scroll on the rest of it to escape.

Thanks!

Comment: Read [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/3757) pull request, which has not been implemented, and see if it helps you. In particular, try [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20572495/three.js/examples/misc_controls_trackball2.html) demo.

Comment: The new code doesn't fix my particular problem (although it did fix the controls not working when I want my renderer element at the bottom of the page- previously I had gotten around this by just not passing an element into the TrackpadControls constructor). I think I'll be able to use Kevin's example to implement the functionality I'm looking for, and I'll issue a pull request when I get it working. Thanks!